# Dynamically create a Google Maps API V3 Script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm trying to use a combination of Google Autocomplete with Google Maps API V3.

A user will enter an address into an address field (page1), click 'Next', and then a lightbox (page2) will appear with the Map of the address that they entered.

So what will happen is that the lat + long (from page1) of the address will being passed into the lightbox URL (page2) as query params. The script below will need to build itself on page-load, using the lat+long.

Below is the default Google Maps

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var address = {lat: lat_address, lng: lng_address};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: address
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: address,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

What I'm unsure about is how to build a script on page-load. Could anyone advise please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just solved this utilizing the function `getQueryVariable` to get the value of each query param from the URL, and then using it in the `initMap` to pass variables on page-load.

```
<script>
  //Function that allows easy access to param->value
  function getQueryVariable(variable)
  {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
    }
    return(false);
  }

  //Initialize the GMap
  function initMap() {
    var latAddress = getQueryVariable('lat_address');
    var latAddress = parseInt(latAddress);

    var lngAddress = getQueryVariable('lng_address');
    var lngAddress = parseInt(lngAddress);

    var address = {lat: latAddress, lng: lngAddress};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: address
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: address,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```